# How to create a view that shows either spinner or edittext on condition?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view

I use recyclerView and a few cardViews with some editTexts on it, for example:[image: cardview]
And now I want to modify the design to programmatically display either spinner or editText based on data given to viewHolder.

I have read the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/custom-components) about the custom view, but I am not sure if self-implementing onDraw, onMeasure, ..., will be the right way.

I'm also looking into [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) but have not understood it yet.

Thanks :)

Comment: What data are you passing to the ViewHolder?

Comment: List<String>, I am trying to config the view like [["Spinner", "Option 1", "Option 2"], ["EditText", "PlaceHolder"]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple way to do this. You don't necessarily need some complex custom view for this. You can just put both `Spinner` and `EditText` on your UI, then just `android:visibility=gone` the view that you don't need currently, and `android:visibility=visible` the one you need.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this before. But as I got multiple components that need either spinner or editText, I was trying to reduce duplicate code.

Comment: Then, you probably need a reusable layout that you just `include` wherever you need it. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts